# How can I tell clang-format to run on every line of a file?

Tags: clang-format

I'm trying to use clang-format to format some source code (since it seems to be the only one that has the formatting options I need) but it seems to act like it is only running its rules if I go past the specified column limit.

I tried setting my column limit to 0, but that seems to produce wildly different formatting than a reasonable limit would produce. And even then, it doesn't always format some lines.

Answer (score 2):

clang-format always runs on every line of a file, not just on the ones violating the column limit. If you find that it isn't doing that, there must be something else wrong.

ColumnLimit:0 indeed does something entirely different (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)